# Jaspersoft - List of possible report related URL parameters?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

what parameters could be added to URL to call a report stored in Jaspersoft Server?

I mean parameters like:

- output=pdf
- j_username=xyz
- j_password=abc
- ...

What else could be passed via URL?

- dataSource?
- encoding?
- output file name?
- format?  (like pdf, rtf, xls, xlsx, ...)
- locale? (like de_DE, en_EN, ...)
- Encoding? (SO-8859-15, UTF-8, Windows-1252, ....)

Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more in the JasperReports-Server-Web-Services-Guide.pdf which comes with the install e.g.

```
userTimezone
userLocale
viewAsDashboardFrame (display menu etc of the server or not)
decorate (display export/save buttons etc)
```

Not sure about passing the datasource, this is normally fixed to the report.